Why we should install postgresql in the Django container?
Why is necessary install postgresql as dependency in a Django backend container?
the Django app is intended to connect to a PostgreSQL DB running in a separate container.
I have the next Dockerfile:
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.12.4-slim-bookworm

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# new
# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install gcc postgresql \
  && apt-get clean

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . .

And I have the next docker-compose.yml file:

services:
  movies:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8009:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - movies-db
  movies-db:
    image: postgres:16
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=movies
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=movies
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:

This is the case in the course "Test-Driven Development with Django, Django REST Framework, and Docker" by testdriven.io

You don't need to install postgres in Django container. Your tutorial apparently is either incomplete or flawed. You can install psycopg2-binary or psycopg[binary] - postgresql APT package may only be necessary to build psycopg2/psycopg wheels. Even if you need to build those wheels for some reason, it's still a build-only dependency, and you can (should?) leverage a multi-stage build to eliminate postgresql from final production image. The only reason it may be necessary is to make manage.py dbshell work which is hardly useful in such setup.

You probably need a C runtime library (libpq5) but not the full PostgreSQL server.  Don't forget to include a default CMD in your image so it knows how to run.
